# addAfter() Singly Linked List Implementation in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

Hi stackoverflow community!

I am trying to implement addAfter() method for my SinglyLinkedList and I thought I was doing it correctly, but nothing is printing out. Would love to see y'alls insight on what I might be missing:

```
public class LinkedList {
private EmployeeNode head;
private EmployeeNode tail;
private int size;

public void addAfter(EmployeeNode node, Employee newEmployee) {
    EmployeeNode newNode = new EmployeeNode(newEmployee);
    newNode.setNext(node.getNext());
    node.setNext(newNode);
    size++;
    if(tail == null) {
        tail = newNode;
    }
  } 
}
```

*To keep the code brief, I have not added the other methods, but everything else works perfectly fine such as append(), addToFront(), removeFromEnd(), printList(), etc.

Main Method:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee janeSmith = new Employee("Jane", "Smith", 44);
    Employee maryJames = new Employee("Mary", "James", 34);
    Employee johnDoe = new Employee("John", "Doe", 78);
    Employee andrewJackson = new Employee("Andrew", "Jackson", 24);
    EmployeeNode node = new EmployeeNode(maryJames);

    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    list.addToFront(janeSmith);
    list.addToFront(maryJames);
    list.addToFront(johnDoe);
    list.addAfter(node, andrewJackson);
    list.printList();
}
```

**Employee Class just has firstName, lastName, and id instance variables as seen in the above instantiations.

EmployeeNode Class:

```
public class EmployeeNode {
private Employee employee;
private EmployeeNode next;

public EmployeeNode(Employee employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
}

public Employee getEmployee() {
    return employee;
}

public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
}

public EmployeeNode getNext() {
    return next;
}

public void setNext(EmployeeNode next) {
    this.next = next;
}

public String toString() {
    return employee.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: The way you have it now, you take some random node which may or may not be in the list (in this case looks like not) and add the other after it. Shouldn't you find the node or at least make sure the node is in the list?

Comment: But the node I created is is added to the list in the main method... right? The node I’m trying to add after is maryJames and that is added to the list first and then after that call is made, I’m adding a new employee (andrewJackson). Is this what you mean? 

I was trying to complete this operation in O(1). There is a O(n) way of doing this where I traverse the list, but I don’t think I need to do it that way.
@ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: `maryJames` is an `Employee`; you do add that to the list which I assume wraps it into an `EmployeeNode`. But `node` is an independent node not in the list at the time you add `andrewJackson`. You can do it the way you want in O(1) but your API seems to be fighting you. because it takes employees and not nodes. You could maybe return the node created in `addToFront`. Somehow you need to have a reference to the node *outside* of the list.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> EmployeeNode node = new EmployeeNode(maryJames);

You are creating a node that contains maryJames **and has no value for next**.

Than you say

> addToFront(maryJames)

You are creating an **different** EmployeeNode that contains maryJames. This EmployeeNode has the 'next' element set correctly (I assume) by the addFront(method).

When you say

> list.addAfter(node, andrewJackson);

You are using the EmployeeNode that does not have 'next' set. And the addAfter() method won't work correctly.

You need to use the instance of EmployeeNode is part of the LinkedList.